# CMake cannot find .so which is symbolic link file

Tags: c++, cmake, symlink, .so

Platform: ubuntu22.04
I'm using cmake to link to a 3rd party library. It looks like:

```
// Those two files are identical. 
// abc.so is the original file and libabc.so is a copy

// ${shared} is an absolute path
${shared}/libabc.so
${shared}/abc.so
```

My CMakeLists.txt:

```
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${shared})

ADD_EXECUTABLE(main ...)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(main libabc.so)
```

So far it works fine. You may have noticed that I have `${shared}/libabc.so` and `${shared}/abc.so` at the same time. They are identical. So I delete libabc.so (abc.so is the original file) and create a link file with
`ln -s relative_path/shared/abc.so relative_path/shared/libabc.so`.
But I got:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -labc: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why do I get this error when libabc.so did exists?

Comment: @user same error: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -labc: No such file or directory. I tried `abc.so` ,`abc`, `libabc.so`, `libabc`.

Comment: @user Problem solved! THANKS!  The `ln -s` path should be absolute. My ${shared} is absolute path. I didn't make that clear.

Comment: @user sorry. I have updated the question to show where `${share}` is. The issue was about `ln` not `link_diretories`. It works before I use `ln`.

Comment: uhh am I blind or have you not shown what the value of `${shared}` is? Now I'm just very confused.

Comment: @user sorry again. I intentionally ignore the value of `${share}`. because it works before I use `ln` (and `${share}` works), so I know that's not the problem. But you are correct about it. I suggest we just ignore `${share}`.

Comment: You can also use a relative path but it must be relative to where the symbolic link is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you ran `ln -s shared/abc.so shared/libabc.so` from the root directory (with current working directory of shell in root directory), it should have instead been `ln -s /shared/abc.so /shared/libabc.so`. You want absolute paths and not relative paths.

Not sure if this applies or not according to your `${shared}` variable, note from [the docs for `link_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/link_directories.html):

> Adds the paths in which the linker should search for libraries. Relative paths given to this command are interpreted as relative to the current source directory

Also, I believe your `target_link_libraries(main libabc.so)` can be `target_link_libraries(main abc)`, [as documented in the `target_link_library` docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) in the "plain library name" form of `<item>` parameters.